# Linux top command CPU usage

Tags: java, linux

I have a Java process which is single threaded running on Linux which is 8 core CPU and 32G memory.

When I run the `top` command, I find that the CPU usage is about `600%`.

I would ask what `600%` really means here(how it calculated), I have thought it should be no more than 100% since it is single threaded.

My process is a time consuming process, I have thought to make it run as multi-threaded, but given the CPU usage, looks multi thread won't help to improve the performance?

Comment: It's consuming 6 cores with, probably, 6 threads. The ps command can show you thread information. You'll have to look much more closely at the process to determine what the threads are doing, when they're doing it, and if they'll keep doing what they're doing to know if more multi-threading will help.

Comment: There is (in truth) no such thing as a single-threaded Java application. There is a garbage collector. And the JVM can start as many internal threads as are required to implement the JVM itself.